# How to point globally installed package to a jupyter/visual studio environment to avoid ModuleNotFoundError: error

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Following the tutorial - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-get-started-text?tabs=python - I am getting error when I run the first cell in `jupyter`

```
WARNING: Package(s) not found: azure-search-documents
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 8
      5 get_ipython().run_line_magic('pip', 'show azure-search-documents')
      7 import os
----> 8 from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
      9 from azure.search.documents.indexes import SearchIndexClient 
     10 from azure.search.documents import SearchClient

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'
```

I have installed `azure-search-documents` and can see them in the terminal

[image]

UPdate - seems the download notebook have the step to install the `azure.search-documents` package commented. I uncommented it and things are working

```
%pip install azure-search-documents --pre
%pip show azure-search-documents

import os
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.search.documents.indexes import SearchIndexClient 
from azure.search.documents import SearchClient
from azure.search.documents.indexes.models import (
    ComplexField,
    CorsOptions,
    SearchIndex,
    ScoringProfile,
    SearchFieldDataType,
    SimpleField,
    SearchableField
)
```

I have change the question topic. Can I point a globally installed package point to notebook?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is due to the Jupyter notebook not being able to find the required module. This could be because the Python environment in which you're running your Jupyter notebook is not the same as the one where you installed the `azure-search-documents` package.

To fix this issue, you can create a separate environment with all the required packages, or you can select an existing environment as kernel which contains all the required packages.

If the notebook is not using the desired environment, you can activate the correct environment within Jupyter by installing the `ipykernel` package and creating a new kernel for that environment.

```bash
# Install ipykernel in the environment where the package is installed
pip install ipykernel

# Add the environment as a new kernel to Jupyter
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=myenv --display-name="Python (myenv)"
```

In VS Code, you can change the environment for below mentioned section:
[image]

The you can select any existing environment as per your requirement:
[image]